# Swift Initialize Struct with optional stored properties

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a Swift newbie and I'm trying to get my head around using Structs with optional properties. I've done quite a bit of searching and got something that works but it feels incredibly inefficient so wondered if there's a better/more manageable way of achieving my goal.

I'd like to use Structs to represent a business but I have no idea in advance which combination of properties any specific business is likely to have. This seems to mean that I have to create an init() for every possible combination of parameters.

Here's a simplified example (I have many more properties):

```
import Foundation

struct Business {
    let name : String
    var web : String?
    var address: String?

    // just the business name
    init(busName: String) {
        self.name = busName
    }

    // business name + website
    init(busName: String, website: String) {
        self.name = busName
        self.web = website
    }

    // business name + address
    init(busName: String, address: String) {
        self.name = busName
        self.address = address
    }

    // business name + website + address
    init(busName: String, website: String, address: String) {
        self.name = busName
        self.web = website
        self.address = address
    }
}
```

I can then initialise the class like this:

```
Business(busName: "Dave's Cafe", website: "http://www.davescafe.com")

Business(busName: "Sarah's Brewhouse", address: "41 Acacia Ave, Smalltown")
```

Is there no way to create some kind of init() where the parameters are optional? If you could point me in the direction of terms or concepts to search for that would be great.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use default values:

```
init(busName: String, website: String? = nil, address: String? = nil) {
    self.name = busName
    self.web = website
    self.address = address
}
```

Then you can call the init like this:

```
_ = Business(busName: "Foo")
_ = Business(busName: "Foo", website: "www.foo.bar")
_ = Business(busName: "Foo", address: "bar")
_ = Business(busName: "Foo", website: "www.foo.bar", address: "bar")
```

Comment: Those should be `String?` and not `String`.

Comment: Thanks @dasdom I tried using the `?` after the type (e.g. `... website: String? ...` as I thought that using that syntax automatically set the value to nil. That didn't work so I didn't try explicitly setting the value to nil. I'll try it now.

Comment: Yes, `String` or `String?` is just a type; it doesn't have much to do with a default value (as long as we're talking about function parameters). You could have had a default value for a String param too, like `init(busName: String = "")` although I think optionals are the right way to go for this.

Comment: @dasdom @jtbandes - thank you both very much. It works! A follow up Q: Where I've initialised the variables at the top of my sample code I've used the `var web : String?` is this pointless/wrong? I thought that I needed to use the `?` because these variables are 'optional'.

Comment: @James the best advice I can offer is...try it! What if you write `var web: String` — does it work? If not, what error message do you get?

Comment: @James The value is automatically set to `nil` if it is optional and no value has been explicitly assigned to it, but only for instance variables, not method parameters.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @NobodyNada - I was sure I'd read something about nil being automatically set for optionals...I wasn't aware of the specifics (still getting to grips with Swift terminology etc)

Answer (score 9):

One approach that you can borrow from other OOP languages is parameter builder pattern. Start with a static method that returns a builder, then add methods for individual parameters, and finally call `build()`:

```
let bakery = Business
    .withName("Black Forest")
    .andWebSite("www.blackforest.com")
    .andAddress("1 Main St, Springfield, IA 98765")
    .build()
```

Here is a skeletal implementation that enables this kind of an API:

```
class Business {
    // Users never call this init, it's for the builder to use
    init(name: String, webSite: String?, address: String?) {
        ...
    }
    // Here is the method the users call:
    static func withName(name: String) {
        return BusinessBuilder(name)
    }
    // This class collects parameters before calling init
    class BusinessBuilder {
        var name : String
        var webSite : String?
        var address: String?
        func andAddress(address: String) -> BusinessBuilder {
            self.address = address
            return self
        }
        func andWebSite(webSite: String) -> BusinessBuilder {
            self.webSite = webSite
            return self
        }
        func build() -> Business {
            return Business(name, webSite, address)
        }
        init(name: String) {
            self.name = name
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you pass as few or as many initializer parameters as you see fit, in any order that you find convenient in a given situation.

The main use of this approach is when you do not know which parameters you are going to get, for example, when they come from an XML or a database. You can call `andXyz` methods in a loop, and then call `build()` when you have no other attributes to set.

Comment: Builder seems unnecessary for OP's simple example, but it could be useful if OP intends to scale to more fields.

Comment: @AMomchilov There is a joke that design patterns are work-arounds for features missing from the programming language. Builder pattern was introduced in Java primarily to compensate for the named parameter feature missing from the language. Swift, on the other hand, addresses this problem natively, so the main reason to use builder in Swift is to be able to pass initializer parameters one at a time.

Comment: Java also didn't have defaulted parameters, so that can compel you to have to break out the builder pattern for a class with only several params.

Answer (score 1):

hope this could help you

```
 struct Business {
    let name : String
    var web : String?
    var address: String?


// you also need use question mark in init progress
init(name: String, web: String?, address: String?) {
    self.name = name
    self.web = web
    self.address = address
    }
}
```

Once you create a object you could use nil on your optional value
For example :

```
var newBusiness = Business(name: "AWS", web: nil, address: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will work but it can be better.
With the `struct` the best approach is to rely on the default initialiser

```
struct Business { // This is all you need
    let name : String
    var web : String?
    var address: String?

    // Look mom no inits
}
```

With such structure there is no need to declare the initialiser. The default `init` has all you need:
[image]

There is a catch. If you still need to declare the additional initialiser - do in in the `extension`, otherwise it will remove the default init.