# import a image from photolibrary to a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview

hi iam trying to import a image from my photo library to a tableview i know how to do this but i have some problem when i import the image it imports to all cells
for ex: if i have 4 diffrent cells and 1 is a car, 2 is a boat, 3 is an airplain and 4 is a skateboard. and each individual cell has its own image allready implomented but when i upload a image of a "bird" then all the cell images becomes the last image i import.

i just want to imploment diffrent images for each cell. thanks.

here is my code:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! 
ViewControllerTableViewCell

    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: (actys[indexPath.row] + ".jpg"))
    cell.myImage.image = cellImage

        cell.myLabel.text = actys[indexPath.row]


    return(cell)

}
```

and in the "import image view controller" i have writen this:

```
 @IBAction func doneEditing(_ sender: Any) {
    if (addTitle.text != ""){
        actys.append(addTitle.text!)
        addTitle.text = ""
    }
    if (newImage.image != nil){
        cellImage = (newImage.image)!
    }
}
```

NOTE: There is a Global variable of "cellImage"

Comment: Please remove the statement cell.myImage.image = cellImage

Comment: cellImage is a global value. CellforRowAtIndexPath delegate will call for each row. so cellImage will set as image of each cell. That may be the problem

Comment: @LineeshKMohan tryed removing: cell.myImage.image = cellImage  but then no image was importet at all

Comment: make cellImage array of images and set image to that array. for ex, cellImage[index] = (newImage.image)! and then get image as ell.myImage.image = cellImage[indexPath.row]

Comment: @LineeshKMohan  ok i will try to do this now

Comment: @LineeshKMohan i made the global variable "cellImage" to var cellImage = [UIImage]() and then i added the [indexpath.row] after cellImage but i get an error of " FATAL ERROR: index out of range " i dont get it

Comment: @jiyar - Lineesh's solution should work.  Alternatively, you could create an object that carries both the text from the addTitleTF and the relevant image.  These objects can be created in importImageViewController and appended to the actys array and then accessed with `actys[indexPath.row].text` and `actys[indexPath.row].image` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`

Comment: @LouisLeung i Will try this im petty new to this so i Will se If I can accomplish this :)

Comment: @jiyar I see. Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553626/swift-initialize-struct-with-optional-stored-properties